# apache + mod_perl + couchbase = occasional connection problems

Tags: apache, connection, couchbase, mod-perl

We use couchbase as session storage for mod_perl scripts. To avoid delays on clients caused by waiting for a new connection we do preconnect to couchbase on child_init apache stage. So during apache restart / new child creation it connects to couchbase automatically and later use that connection during apche child lifetime.

Generally everything works fine, but sometimes we got the following errors during that preconnection:

```
Couldn't connect: 0x13 (Operation not supported) at /perl/lib64/perl5/Couchbase/Bucket.pm line 38.
```

Usually it appears during apache restart and on several (or dozens) of childs, and almost never on one child only. Usually restarting apache again solves the problem.

What can cause such a problems? Is it a problem with code / server configuration / couchbase server itself?

May be it caused somehow with a lot of reconnections at the same time? Some ulimits stuff / or selinux restrictions?

**UPD:** versions

```
OS:
 Centos 6, 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64

libcouchbase:
 libcouchbase-devel.x86_64  2.4.7-1.el6
 libcouchbase2-core.x86_64 2.4.7-1.el6
 libcouchbase2-libevent.x86_64 2.4.7-1.el6

couchbase server:
 2.2.0 community edition (build-837)

SDK:
 perl  (Couchbase::Core v2.0.2)
```

connection code (isolated & simplified):

```
# in mod_perl environment
use Couchbase;
use Couchbase::Bucket;
use Couchbase::Document;
use Apache2::ServerUtil ();

my $cb = undef; 
# connection handler, initialized once, used during apache child lifetime

sub connect_couchbase_on_child_init {
    my ($child_pool, $s) = @_; 
    my $dsn = 'couchbase://192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2/my_bucket_name?detailed_errcodes=1';
    eval { $cb = Couchbase::Bucket->new($dsn); };
    # here we get the occasional warnings during apache restarts
    if ($@) { warn "COUCHBASE CONNECTION ERROR! $@"; $cb = undef; } 
    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

Apache2::ServerUtil->server->push_handlers(PerlChildInitHandler => \&connect_couchbase_on_child_init);

# in request handlers it used with the following calls (only if connected):
# $doc = Couchbase::Document->new($key);
# $cb->get($doc);
# ...   
# $cb->replace($doc);
# ... 
# $cb->insert($doc);
# ...
# $cb->remove($doc);
```

Comment: It might be helpful to know the versions of the Couchbase client and SDK that you are using as well as the connection code you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using server 2.2.0 and because this seems to happen when you are connecting many clients at once, my theory is that you are receiving the last error from the server. The current client bootstrap process attempts using bootstrap over memcached (which is only supported from version >= 2.5.0 of the server), that fails and it attempts to use 'terse' bootstrapping (again, only supported on >= 2.5.0 of the server) and finally 'classic' HTTP (which is available on all versions).

Add the following options to your DSN/connection string to cut out some of the steps for your server. Note that should you ever upgrade to >= 2.5 these options should be removed:

- `bootstrap_on=http` Does not try memcached bootstrap
- `http_urlmode=2` Uses the pre-2.5 style of bootstrapping by default

These two options will not necessarily *fix* your issue, but they will at least cut out some of the initial connection time, and perhaps show a clearer reason for the error (you can also set `LCB_LOGLEVEL=5` in the environment to get actual logging).

In your case, the connection string would be:

```
couchbase://192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2/my_bucket_name?detailed_errcodes=1&bootstrap_on=http&http_urlmode=2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I will also try to play with LCB_LOGLEVEL=5 if it want help. Should that var be set on client or on server? Where the logs will appear?

Comment: Should be set on the client. The logs will appear on stderr

Comment: @MarkNunberg would upgrading to a newer version of community edition fix this?

Comment: After changing connection string as described error messages changed, now we get "Couldn't connect: 0x17 (Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout)". Now I should try to play with config_total_timeout and config_node_timeout, right? Which are default values for it?

Comment: @Kirk Upgrading to a version above 2.5 may indirectly solve the issue, assuming the slowdown is due to the overhead in the cluster's HTTP API and not the network itself.

Comment: @mvf The defaults `config_total_timeout` is 5 seconds and `config_node_timeout` is 2 seconds; meaning it will spend a maximum time of 5 seconds total trying to configure, spending a maximum of 2 seconds per node before trying the next node (if the 5 seconds is not up yet)